# postgres to grab the first N most populous groups and put the rest in an "Other" group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the columns `status`, `operator`, and `cost`, where the columns `status` and `operator` are categorical and I want to sum up the `cost` per (`status`, `operator`) pair. Usually I would do this with a simple statement like

```
SELECT SUM(cost), status, operator FROM my_table GROUP BY status, operator;
```

but the hard part is there could be 100s of unique operators which I can't visualize for the client in a meaningful way. What I want to be able to do is only explicitly show the top `N` many `operator` categories (meaning to top `N` operators that have the highest `SUM(cost)` across the entire dataset) and then group all of the remaining rows in an "Other" operator. An inefficient way to do this would be the following:

```
-- letting N = 12
SELECT
  SUM(cost),
  status,
  CASE
    WHEN operator IN (
      SELECT t.operator
      FROM my_table AS t
      GROUP BY t.operator ORDER BY SUM(t.cost) DESC
      LIMIT 12
    ) THEN operator
    ELSE 'Other'
  END AS operator
FROM my_table
GROUP BY
  status,
  CASE 
    WHEN operator IN (
      SELECT t.operator
      FROM my_table AS t
      GROUP BY t.operator ORDER BY SUM(t.cost) DESC
      LIMIT 12
    ) THEN operator 
    ELSE 'Other'
  END;
```

While the inefficient way works, in production it is far too slow. In actuality, the `cost` is not a simple column in a table but is computed by a subquery that is very slow to compute and the table is large, so I can't afford to use the `CASE` statement with an `IN` clause. What I would rather do is somehow have the full table where I use the GROUP BY statement I listed first in a FROM-clause subquery, then aggregate that to get the top N `operator` categories and an "Other" category. I tried to do this with window functions but I don't really understand how those work and I could not find something that got the right answer. If somebody could help it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The `cost` column is not an actual column. I should have been more clear. It's computed by a very expensive subquery so I want to compute the `cost` for each row of the original table as few times as possible.

Example:

Say we have a table that looks like:

```
pk  |  status   |     operator      |        cost         
----+-----------+-------------------+----------------------
 1  |    A      |       op_1        |         1
 2  |    A      |       op_1        |         5
 3  |    A      |       op_1        |         3
 4  |    A      |       op_1        |         7
 5  |    B      |       op_2        |         10
 6  |    B      |       op_2        |         15
 7  |    A      |       op_3        |         100
 8  |    A      |       op_4        |         1000
 9  |    B      |       op_5        |         12000
 10 |    A      |       op_5        |         10200
 11 |    B      |       op_5        |         10020
```

If I only want the top 3 operators (meaning the three operators with the highest SUM(cost) - in this case operators 3, 4, 5), the query should return:

```
  status   |     operator      |        cost         
-----------+-------------------+----------------------
    B      |       op_5        |         32220
    A      |       op_4        |         1000
    A      |       op_3        |         100
    B      |       Other       |         25
    A      |       Other       |         16
```

In this example, operators 1-2 get rolled up into the "Other" operator, since we only want the top 3 given explicitly. So the first "Other" row in the result table sums all rows where `status=B` and `operator` is not one of the top three operators. The second "Other" row sums up all the rows where `status=A` and `operator` is not one of the top three operators.

Comment: I think you should add some sample data to your question.  The question is not clear enough to me to venture an answer right now.

Comment: But you will always need to calculate the cost for each row, right?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added an examle at the end.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes. I'm trying to write a query where I need to compute the cost as few times as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have converted your query from sub-query to join. You can use `Left join` as follows:

```
SELECT
  SUM(cost),
  status,
  CASE
    WHEN tt.operator is not null 
    THEN tt.operator
    ELSE 'Other'
  END AS operator
FROM my_table t
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT t.operator FROM my_table AS t 
      GROUP BY t.operator
      ORDER BY SUM(t.cost) DESC LIMIT 12 ) tt
On t.operator = tt.operator
GROUP BY
  status,
  CASE
    WHEN tt.operator is not null 
    THEN tt.operator
    ELSE 'Other'
  END;
```

Now, comming to what I understood from description. You want total 13 or less rows(12 operator and 1 other) for particular `status` if there is N=12. You can use `row_number` window function as follows

```
SELECT SUM(cost), 
       status,
       Operator
From
(SELECT SUM(cost), 
       status, 
       Case when Row_number() over (partition by stqtus order by sum(cost) desc) <= 12 
           then operator
           else 'Others'
       end as operator
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY status, operator) t
GROUP BY status, operator;
```

Comment: Yeap @jkoeller, first query was based on your own example and second is according to description. Keep coding!! :)

Comment: This is close but not quite right. This produces a statement that will give back the top 12 operators and the remaining operators per status. However, it does not group by the top 12 operators in the entire dataset. I tried this and when I did a COUNT on UNIQUE operators it came out to 112. Not 13.

Reading your description "total 13 or less rows for particular status" isn't quite what I'm looking for. I'm looking to group by the top 12 operators, and then lump all the remaining operators into an "other" group